# How to select multiple images in expo

Tags: javascript, reactjs, react-native, ecmascript-6, react-redux

I am working on react native application and I am using expo lib. I want functionality to select multiple images from gallery but I am failed because I am new to React Native . Could someone please help me how to select multiple images in expo .

**code**

```
    let result = await ImagePicker.launchImageLibraryAsync({
        mediaTypes: ImagePicker.MediaTypeOptions.All,
        quality: 1,
        allowsMultipleSelection: true,
        base64: false,
    });
```

Answer (score 8):

It seems like that `allowsMultipleSelection` only works for web, as stated in their documentation:

> `allowsMultipleSelection (boolean)` -- **(Web only)** Whether or not to
>   allow selecting multiple media files at once.

To be able to do this on Android/iOS you probably should use this library - [expo-image-picker-multiple](https://www.npmjs.com/package/expo-image-picker-multiple).

Comment: The document states that it's for iOS, Android, and Web for the option of the API at least as of this writing.

Answer (score 2):

I know this was posted a couple years ago but I just ran into this issue and luckily Expo's ImagePicker has been upgraded in SDK 46.0 to allow multi-image selection on iOS 14+, Android, and Web! To upgrade to this SDK version just follow this guide: https://blog.expo.dev/expo-sdk-46-c2a1655f63f7

I did this and am now able to use ImagePicker in my app on iOS to select multiple images at once!!

Answer (score 1):

For expo users, i worked in a library for this purpose... Under the hood uses expo-media-library (if you don't want use the library you can check the code to do your picker), the package is called [expo-image-multiple-picker](https://www.npmjs.com/package/expo-image-multiple-picker)